# Codeigniter ActiveRecord and this->db->query conflict

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am experiencing a strange phenomenon while mixing $this->db->where() and $this->db->query().

```
if (!empty($args) && is_array($args)) {
    foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
        $this->db->where_in($field, $value);
    }
}
$result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ...')->result_array();
```

While I can understand it is probably better to not mix ActiveRecord and regular queries, I am experiencing that the WHERE clause I am building up with `$this->db->where_in()` is affecting subsequent queries (i.e., the clause executes on next query).

Should all my queries be rewritten to either not use ActiveRecord, or to use ONLY ActiveRecord? Or is there a way to prevent this "clash"? I thought about $ths->db->flush_cache() but I am not using database caching, and using it does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not calling `db->where_in` in a loop. Consider instead

```
if (!empty($args) && is_array($args)) 
{
    foreach ($args as $key => $value)
    {
        $values[] = $value;
    }
    $this->db->where_in($field, $values);
}
```

In truth the loop in not needed if $args is an indexed (as opposed to associative) array. You could simply remove the `foreach` and use

```
 $this->db->where_in($field, $args);
```

You probably shouldn't mix Query Builder (previously known as Active Record) and `db->query()`. The Query Builder (QB) methods essentially assemble a statement that you would provide to `db->query()` and then, pretty much literally calls `query("The statement that QB built")`.

IMO, it is almost always easier to type the query statement and use it in `$this->db->query("Select * from ...");`. Query Builder is great but is often more work that it is worth.

In your example you should probably stick to Query Builder. That can still be very concise. If you're looking for all fields from a single table then `db->get` will do the job.

```
$result = $this->db->get('table_name')->result_array();
```

Typically QB clears all the various elements created that go into the statement when the statement is executed with a get, insert, or update call. You can start fresh at any point with this call.

```
$this->db->reset_query();
```